# NetSuite: Putting a Custom report on a Dashboard

Tags: netsuite

I just created a report of Type "Transactions". I needed a report for Item Receipts and this seemed to be the best thing.

The report is built and looks as we want. However, I cannot figure out any way to put it on the dashboard. It appears that Report Snapshots only work with built in reports. Is there any way to do this in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

IF you  are trying to add a Search Report , in home screen click 'personalise' then in 'standard content' select 'custom search'.

After that you can see a dashboard in your home screen. click on setup then add the search report you want to display

Comment: A saved search and a report are 2 different things in NetSuite. I know how to do a saved search. I need to be able to do a custom report